# Command + Shift + 0 (Zero) to pop up iOS reference library, what is the shortcut to go back to xCode?

Tags: xcode, shortcut

Command + Shift + 0 (Zero) to pop up iOS reference library, what is the shortcut to go back to xCode again? Single screen is killing me, so used to work on extended screen :(.

Comment: what is extended screen?

Comment: Extended screen is Dual Monitor, nothing to do with xCode. Easy for us to refer on second screen while coding on first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the standard window-manipulation key combinations. For example, Command-W to close the window (although you have to switch to Command-Shift-W if there are multiple tabs open and you want to close the whole window rather than just the current tab). Or Command-` and Command-Shift-` to cycle forward and backward among the windows.